# Can we please Burninate the Mountain Identifying tag?

Tags: support

Can we please [Burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request) the [mountain-identifying](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountain-identifying) tag?

[It shouldn't be on topic](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/453/questions-relating-to-identifying-geological-landmarks) and may lead people to think that these questions are acceptable.

Comment: the question you link doesn't make it clear whether it is acceptable or not; it is merely referring to your own answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it needs a true burnination. Now that it doesn't have any questions, it should disappear within 24 hours. If it comes back repeatedly, we can burninate it.