# Species Identification

Tags: discussion, scope

Just curious, there have been a couple questions pertaining to identification of species, how do these questions differ from [these](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/453/questions-relating-to-identifying-geological-landmarks).  Just trying to keep things consistent on what is on topic/off topic.

Comment: Would the mountain Identification question have been on topic if the original question had a further point such as, Has it been climbed? or is it a climbable peak?

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering when this question was coming up.

The biggest issue: All plant identification is covered in the [identification](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) tag on [**Gardening & Landscaping** beta](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) (by far the biggest tag there), and there is some overlap there and with the [species-identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification) tag on [**Biology** beta](https://biology.stackexchange.com/), which covers the identification of any living organism, even microscopic.

With two sites where these questions are already on-topic, including this in the scope of *another* site doesn't seem constructive, and may lead to some confusion as to where you should ask your question.

About mountain identification, this has the potential for creating lots of unanswered question, if allowed in scope, because many mountains could be very difficult to identify. I think you did right to close the [mountain-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountain-identification) questions. Before the [**Help Center > Asking**](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is updated with more specific guidelines, *you* (the community) will decide what's on- off-topic, by vtc, and/or posting on meta. once you have enough feedback on what could be on-the-line or controversial topics, you can include/exclude them in the help center.