# Why does close as Off-Topic only feature our meta as option?

Tags: support

I wanted to vote to close [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/small-mushroom-in-massachusetts-identification) as off-topic so that it might be migrated to biology SE (discussion on this was once started [here](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/548/species-identification)). I could not do so as only our meta is featured as option under "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network". Why is this the case?

I now just flagged it for moderator attention and explained my intent. Is this the "intended" way to do this or am I missing something.

Answer (score 7):

This is normal for a beta site. On graduation migration destinations are decided based on where posts have been migrated.

Until then, use a moderator flag and we can manually migrate.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but that question is fine here. It should not be migrated.  We have had identification questions here before, and this one fits right in.  Understanding what species you encounter in the outdoors is part of enjoying the outdoors.

Comment: I thought that there would be such arguments and therefore added the link to the question concerning this. I would like to see a real discussion on this (not just now two posts about it). I think it is more viable to have such question in one place instead of splitting it. I see that it is relevant to the outdoors, but still is more appropriate on biology. There will also be more knowledge around there. Just my opinion.

Comment: @ims: Since it was posted here, and it's on topic here, it should stay here.  It may well be on topic elsewhere, and maybe even get a better answer, but that's the OP's call.  The OP may not be on Biology SE, just for one reason to post here.

Comment: Imsodin - as Olin said, if a post is on topic on a site,migration is not generally approved, unless it gets no answers, the OP requests it, or enough people vote for it to be migrated. SE policy is *not* to migrate just to have them in one place.